# Why is least squared loss sometimes written multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: regression, least-squares

The base least squares formula that makes sense to me is:
$$\sum(y^{(i)}-h_{\theta}(x^{(i)}))^2$$
Where $h_{\theta}$ is the hypothesis function, $y^{(i)}\in R, x^{(i)} \in R$. Then sometimes I see the function multiplied by $\frac{1}{m}$ where $m$ is the number of data points, which makes sense that's taking an average, but other times I see it just multipled by $\frac{1}{2}$ like in these Stanford ML notes: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/LinearRegression/. But I don't really know the purpose of this, besides it cancels out the 2 when you take the derivative of the loss, but that doesn't really seem to provide much utility and I can't really think of any other benefit it gives.

Comment: It's literally just to cancel out the 2 when you take the derivative. Makes the maths a little bit more straightforward because you don't have a factor of 2 floating around. Also makes it look a bit more like the log-likelihood of a Gaussian which is useful for if you assume data form Gaussian iid errors around the hypothesis function

Answer (score 6):

> it cancels out the 2 when you take the derivative of the loss

That's it. This is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just for mathematical convenience. Later on, you will be taking the derivative of this mean squares, so by multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ beforehand, you are getting rid of the factor of 2.

Comment: I feel like it's a pretty simple equation that doesn't really need to be made more convenient unless your hypothesis function is something insane.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct to note that this is for convenience when derivatives are taken. However, that convenience is justified by the fact that positive scalar multiples of functions (along with other strictly increasing transformations) have the same critical points (same maxima, same minima, same saddles), just achieving different values. It is those critical points that are of concern in the optimization being discussed, rather the function values of those critical points, as the minima or maxima (depends on if loss is minimized or "gain" is maximized) are the parameter estimates.

[I once addressed this on the Data Science Stack.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/53189/73930)